RBE duplication in Hyperworks 2022
Let's assume that I have 50 rows of elements in cone from the basement to the top. And so I need to do rbe contact between each row of elements, but I don't want to repeat the operation every time. Is there any opportunity to duplicate rbe and tie it with corresponding nodes
